# Jenkins download plugin analysis-core

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to download the `Static Analysis Utilities` plugin from Jenkins  v1.618. I keep getting `Failure`. I tried this several times since the yesterday but same result. The exception is as follows:

```
hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to download from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/analysis-core/1.72/analysis-core.hpi (redirected to: http://ftp-nyc.osuosl.org/pub/jenkins/plugins/analysis-core/1.72/analysis-core.hpi)
  at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:797)
  at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1148)
  at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1309)
  at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1126)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Inconsistent file length: expected 3186580 but only got 6836
  at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:784)
  ... 7 more
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/NC4h-Y1D4iY

BTW i had the similar issue while installing jenkins with plugins in vagrant using ansible. I re-ran it and it went fine.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/gotwarlost/jenkins-classloader/tree/master/testData

Comment: Thanks @AnujaLamahewa. I ended up downloading the `analysis-core.hpi` and put it under jenkins/plugins and that worked.